# RB4 2GB won't boot, ACT keeps blinking

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

today my RPi 4 2GB stopped booting, used multiple SD cards that work with my RPi 3, Power light is on and not blinking but ACT is a bit dim and flashed continuously, with or without a SD card in.
Anyone got any idea what the issue might be? Haven't found a similar problem.

Comment: Hopefully you are using the official 5.1V 3.0A power supply? Here is the boot sticky: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: @CoderMike I am using the official power supply , tried another one and no change. I tried everything in the thread and nothing worked

Comment: So even eeprom boot recovery failed?

Comment: That is correct, power led never blinked, is constantly on and act led blinking rapidly. There isn't any HDMI output, no green screen no nothing.